# LibClang: parse a header file with definitions from another header file?

Tags: c, clang, libclang

I am using the latest LibClang to parse some C header files. The code I process comes from CXUnsavedFile's (it is all generated dynamically and nothing lives on disk). For Example:

FileA.h contains:

```
struct STRUCT_A {
  int a;
  struct STRUCT_B foo;
};
```

FileB.h contains:

```
struct STRUCT_B {
  int b;
};
```

When parsing fileA.h with the following code snippet:

```
CXUnsavedFile unsaved_files[2];

unsaved_files[0].Filename = "fileA.h";
unsaved_files[0].Contents = fileA_contents;
unsaved_files[0].Length   = strlen( fileA_contents );

unsaved_files[1].Filename = "fileB.h";
unsaved_files[1].Contents = fileB_contents;
unsaved_files[1].Length   = strlen( fileB_contents );

tu = clang_parseTranslationUnit(
    index,
    "fileA.h",
    argv, // "-x c-header -target i386-pc-win32"
    argc,
    (CXUnsavedFile *)&unsaved_files,
    2,
    CXTranslationUnit_None
);

CXCursor cur = clang_getTranslationUnitCursor( tu );

clang_visitChildren( cur, visitor, NULL );
```

I get the error "`field has incomplete type 'struct STRUCT_B'`" which makes sense as I have not included fileB.h in order to define struct STRUCT_B.

Adding an "#include <fileB.h>" does not work (`fatal error: 'fileB.h' file not found`).

**How do I get parsing fileA.h to work when one or more needed definitions are present in another CXUnsavedFile fileB.h?**

Comment: Well, if `fileA.h` depends on `fileB.h`, why not just switch the order of the files?

Comment: It is not found because clang is only searching global include dirs. Use " instead of <>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure this will help you, but here are two remarks:

1. Although it isn't explicitly mentioned in the documentation, I think that the `Filename` field should contain a full path to the file (which could be important for inclusions, especially when there are "-I" switches in the command-line)
2. from [libclang's documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/structCXUnsavedFile.html#aa8bf5d4351628ee8502b517421e8b418) (emphasis mine):

   > `const char* CXUnsavedFile::Filename`
   >
   > ---
   >
   > The file whose contents have not yet been saved.
   >   **This file must already exist in the file system.**

   I suspect `libclang` relies on the filesystem for almost everything (finding the correct file to include, checking it exists, ...) and only account for `CXUnsavedFile`s at the last step, when actual content must be read.

If you can, I would suggest creating empty files in a memory filesystem. This would not incur much resource usage, and could help `libclang` find the correct include files.

Comment: Thanks, yes by including a full path, e.g "c:\\fileA.h" and passing a dir on the command line "-Ic:\\" we can reference unsaved files by including them as expected.